# The background music does not stop when player leave the area

Tags: lua, roblox

Hello so today i just learn roblox studio to create a game. Im making a script where certain music will play if the player hit / enter the area and if the player leave the area music will also change. I tried to create the script but i got an error, the error is the background music does not stop and the elevator music does not play when player leave the part / area. Is there something wrong the code ?

```
local SoundService = game:GetService("SoundService")
local backgroundMusic = SoundService.BackgroundMusic
local elevatorMusic = SoundService.Elevator
local part = workspace.InsideBuilding
local musicPlayed = false
local CurrentArea = nil



elevatorMusic:Play()


part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local character = game.Players:playerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if character:IsA("Player") and character then 
        if part ~= CurrentArea then
            CurrentArea = part
            elevatorMusic:Stop()
            if not backgroundMusic.IsPlaying then
                backgroundMusic:Play()
            end
        elseif CurrentArea == nil then
            backgroundMusic:Stop()
            elevatorMusic:Play()
        end 
    end
end)
```

The local part is the floor of the building.

Answer (score 1):

You should Run the part when the music plays when the player touches the part:

also you did the touching mechanism wrong

```
local SoundService = game:GetService("SoundService")
    local backgroundMusic = SoundService.BackgroundMusic
    local elevatorMusic = SoundService.Elevator
    local part = workspace.InsideBuilding
    local musicPlayed = false
    local CurrentArea = nil
    
    
    
    
    
    
    part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        if hit.parent:findfirstchild("Humaniod")
          elevatorMusic:Play()    
    if part ~= CurrentArea then
                CurrentArea = part
                elevatorMusic:Stop()
                if not backgroundMusic.IsPlaying then
                    backgroundMusic:Play()
                end
            elseif CurrentArea == nil then
                backgroundMusic:Stop()
                elevatorMusic:Play()
            end 
        end
    end)
```

hope this helped you